# How can i apply multiple filter on different value columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns A, B & C. A has the store numbers (numbers), B has the Product item codes (numerical codes) and C has its stock levels (numbers). I want to put a first filter on "B" then a second filter on "C". Inputs for both these filters will be derived from cell E1 & E2 respectively.

```
i tried the following code

Dim rCrit1 As Range, rCrit2 As Range, rRng1 As Range, rRng2 As Range

Set rCrit1 = Range("E1")
Set rCrit2 = Range("E2")
Set rRng1 = Range("A1:C10")
Set rRng2 = Range("A1:C10")
With rRng1
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=rCrit1, Operator:=xlAnd
End With
With rRng2
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=rCrit2, Operator:=xlBottom10Items
End With*
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a second variable for the same range.

```
With rRng1
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=rCrit1, Operator:=xlAnd
    .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=rCrit2, Operator:=xlAnd
End With
```

The `field:=` is what determines which column is being used to filter

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad . i changed the code but still no success. it returns me no values.

Comment: Maybe you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58651221/edit) to add sample data and expected outcome?